# How can I manually adjust or align the position of each legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I manually adjust the position of each line legend (and for example align these pairs)? The legends become not aligned when the text lengths are different.

```
legend = LineLegend[
   ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[6], {"First legend", "Second", "Third",
     "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}, 
   Spacings -> {0.3, 2}];
Plot[{x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x, 6 x}, {x, 1, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Top]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LegendLayout -> {"Column", 3}`

[image]